# Textboxes in an Array, Connect 4

Tags: c#, arrays, button, textbox

I'm trying to create a Connect 4 game using textboxes and buttons.
If you click on the button, the textbox background color is filled in and the text will either be filled with x or y.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Output_textBox.AppendText("You have inserted in Column 2");
        Output_textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

        TextBox[] boxes = { textBox21, textBox22, textBox23, textBox24, textBox25, textBox26 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {    
            if (boxes[i].BackColor != SystemColors.HotTrack)
            {
                boxes[i].BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
                boxes[i].Text = "Y";
            }
        }    
    }
```

(edited on 11/6/2013 2:25pm)
The Code above doesn't seem to work even though it seems to make perfect sense to me that it should. 
 What i want is for the textbox to turn one by one. So if i click on the button once. textbox11 changes first. Then if textbox11 is filled, textbox12 is filled next when i click on the button again etc. 
The coloring needs to be from bottom to top in a column

About me: I'm new to coding. Sorry for the trouble

Thank you in advanced

Comment: How about if you add `return;` after `textBox.BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;`? That would mean it only colors the first TextBox which is empty.

Comment: i tried your suggestion. However it only colors in the very first TextBox and when I click again, it doesnt color the other ones

Comment: Is the first one still empty? If you want to color the first one which is empty and not already colored, you need to add that to the if statement,`if (textBox.Text == string.Empty && textBox.backColor != SystemColors.HotTrack)`

Comment: that last line really helped. However, I forgot to tell you as its a connect 4 game, there is other textboxes (they named textbox21,22,31,32 etc) according to the row and column. It seems to color from right to left instead of coloring from button to top in a column. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: i just changed my code. Would you mind looking at it again please

Comment: Your `for` is incorrect, it should be for `(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)`. Probably not going to help you though, you're still looping through everything. You're not giving your program enough logic to handle what you want. You need to either loop through all of the boxes and be able to tell if they should be colored or not, or make a definite order and only loop to the first one you need to change.

Comment: so if i get rid of the for loop. Instead i put a counter for every time i click on the button. so then it be boxes[counter] would that work better?